# How to right click on a folder and select from context menu using pywinauto?

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I'm writing automation tests for a cloud syncing desktop application. The problem I'm facing is that I cannot select a sub-folder from a window and I cannot select an option from context menu when right-click on a folder.

Example:

```
import pywinauto

pywinauto.Application().Start(r'explorer.exe')
explorer = pywinauto.Application().Connect(path='explorer.exe')
NewWindow = explorer.Window_(top_level_only=True, active_only=True, class_name='CabinetWClass')
NewWindow.AddressBandRoot.ClickInput()
NewWindow.TypeKeys(r'Program Files{ENTER}', with_spaces=True, set_foreground=False)
ProgramFiles = explorer.Window_(top_level_only=True, active_only=True, title='Program Files', class_name='CabinetWClass')
explorer.WaitCPUUsageLower(threshold=5)
item = ProgramFiles.FolderView.GetItem('7-Zip')
item.EnsureVisible()
item.RightClickInput()
```

response:

```
    item = ProgramFiles.FolderView.GetItem('7-Zip')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 243, in __getattr__
    ctrls = _resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 758, in _resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'FolderView' in '[u'', u'ShellView', u'ShellViewSHELLDLL_DefView', 'Progress', u'UIRibbonCommandBar', u'24', u'25', u'20', u'21', u'22', u'23', u'WorkerW', u'0', u'ScrollBar', u'4', u'8', 'TreeView', u'DirectUIHWND', u'Address band toolbarToolbar', u'SHELLDLL_DefView', u'Namespace Tree ControlNamespaceTreeControl', u'UniversalSearchBand', u'WorkerW1', u'WorkerW0', u'Program FilesShellTabWindowClass', u'Tree ViewTreeView', u'3', u'7', u'NamespaceTreeControl', u'NUIPane', u'Search Box', u'CtrlNotifySink0', u'CtrlNotifySink1', u'CtrlNotifySink2', u'CtrlNotifySink3', u'Navigation buttons', u'Program Files', u'Address Band Root', u'SeparatorBand2', u'Navigation buttonsToolbar', u'Up band toolbarToolbar', u'WorkerW2', u'DUIViewWndClassName', u'UIRibbonCommandBarDock', u'Namespace Tree Control', u'2', u'6', u'ShellTabWindowClass', u'ReBarAddress', 'Toolbar3', u'RibbonUIRibbonWorkPane', u'Toolbar1', u'Toolbar0', 'Toolbar5', 'Toolbar4', u'Up band toolbar', u'11', u'10', u'13', u'12', u'15', u'14', u'17', u'16', u'19', u'18', u'UIRibbonDockTopUIRibbonCommandBarDock', u'UIRibbonDockTop', u'DirectUIHWND1', u'DirectUIHWND0', u'DirectUIHWND3', u'DirectUIHWND2', u'Address: C:\\Program FilesToolbar', u'Address: C:\\Program Files', u'Breadcrumb Parent', u'SearchEditBoxWrapperClass', u'UpBand', u'CtrlNotifySink', u'TravelBand', u'1', u'5', u'9', 'Toolbar', 'ReBar', u'NetUIHWND', u'Address band toolbar', u'SeparatorBand0', u'SeparatorBand1', u'RibbonUIRibbonCommandBar', u'Ribbon2', u'Ribbon1', u'Ribbon0', 'Toolbar2', u'Tree View', u'UIRibbonWorkPane', u'ReBar0', u'ReBar1', 'ReBar2', u'SeparatorBand', u'Ribbon']'
```

Also, when I look on SWAPY, I cannot find a list with all sub-folders.

I have windows 10 x64, python 64bit. The python and cmd are running as administrator. I have also tried on Windows 7 x86 and x64 without success.

@Vasily Ryabov, can you help me with an example?

Comment: Also I've tried with print_control_identifiers() and there was no FolderView

Comment: pywinauto 0.5.4 doesn't support folder list view. But UIA branch on GitHub is able to deal with that. I have no example with `explorer.exe` right now. But it's on the roadmap. If you wish to try new functionality before the 0.6.0 release, please let me know. There is no exact date for 0.6.0 but I hope to finish it this summer.

Comment: Hey Vasily, thank you for reply. I really want to test and try the new functionalities before release. How we proceed?

Comment: pywinauto 0.6.0 is out. [The main repo readme](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/README.md) contains working `explorer.exe` example now.

Answer (score 3):

To continue vasiliy ryabov's answer. It can be accomplished with the latest UIA branch of pywinauto. Let's say you have a `Video` folder opened and you try to right click on a sub-folder called `My Home Videos`. When a context menu is popped up we just click on `Open` menu item:

```
dsk = pywinauto.Desktop(backend='uia')
explorer = pywinauto.Application().Connect(path='explorer.exe')

# chain actions: set focus and right click after that
explorer.Video.MyHomeVideos.set_focus().click_input(button='right')

# Here we get to the popup menu
dsk.Context.Open.click_input()
```

Comment: Another way to access context menu: `explorer.PopupMenu["Open"].set_focus().click_input()` instead of `dsk.Context.Open.click_input()`

Answer (score 0):

(WARNING: for early testing of UIA branch of pywinauto; will replace the answer after pywinauto 0.6.0 is out)

If you're familiar with Git, just clone the main repo, switch to UIA branch, install comtypes with `pip install comtypes` and then install pywinauto (UIA branch) by `python setup.py install`.

Explorer should be run with `app = Application(backend='uia').start("explorer.exe")`. Other things would look almost the same except PEP8 names for methods (`click_input` instead of `ClickInput` etc.).

For the context menu you can use the following (because MenuWrapper is not ready for UIA)

```
app2 = Application(backend='native').connect(process=app.process)
app2.PopupMenu.Wait('visible', timeout=15).Menu().GetMenuPath("item name")[0].Click()`
```

ListViewWrapper is implemented for UIA very recently. Any feedback is appreciated.

---

EDIT1:
I could take list of files so (assume `apps/MFC_Samples` folder is open):

```
explorer = pywinauto.Application(backend='uia').connect(path='explorer.exe')
explorer.MFC_Samples.ItemsView.children_texts()[1:]
```

Output:

```
[u'x64', u'BCDialogMenu.exe', u'CmnCtrl1.exe', u'CmnCtrl2.exe', u'CmnCtrl3.exe',
u'CtrlTest.exe', u'mfc100u.dll', u'RebarTest.exe', u'RowList.exe', u'TrayMenu.exe']
```

I'll prepare more detailed example later.

Comment: After running python setup.py install I received the following error: 
  File "C:\pywinauto-64-UIA\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 923, in TreeViewWrapper
    UIA_TreeControlTypeId]
NameError: name 'UIA_TreeControlTypeId' is not defined

Comment: I have uninstalled python and removed all dependencies, then installed Python 64bit, comtypes, pillow and Python for Windows Extensions (i had an error : No module named win32api).

Comment: You can install pyWin32 extensions with `C:\Python27_x64\Scripts\pip.exe install pypiwin32`, the same for others. Never met the first problem. I need more info to reproduce it.