# Handling Context Menu of the taskbar icon with pywinauto

Tags: python, windows, automation, taskbar, pywinauto

I am trying to automate the exiting operation on one of the apps. The app's icon is located in the taskbar. I was successfull in opening that icon's context menu with the modified code that I have found on stackoverflow:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

app= "Service is enabled."

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe")
st = app.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
t = st.child_window(title="Notification Chevron").wrapper_object()
t.click()

time.sleep(1)

list_box = Application(backend="uia").connect(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win = list_box.window(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win.wait('visible', timeout=30, retry_interval=3)

# time.sleep(1)

appOpened= list_box_win.child_window(title = app)
appOpened.click_input(button = "right")
```

After the execution of the code above I get to the point when the `context menu` is opened:
[image]

The next thing that I want to do is to click on `Exit`, I have tried doing it by specifying the mouse click coordinates, but I have noticed that the position of the parent icon is changing from time to time.
What I would like to do is to get the handle on the `Exit` button and send click automatically.

------**Edit**-------

The icon is located in the hidden icons

Answer (score 1):

So you want to access to the right click context menu. As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38416206/12540580), you can do something like :

```py
listbox.PopupMenu["Exit"].set_focus().click_input()
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have added the line `list_box_win.PopupMenu["Exit"].set_focus().click_input()
` at the end of the code in the questiom, but I am getting a match error: `MatchError: Could not find 'PopupMenu' in 'dict_keys([different buttons here]) `

Comment: if I repalce `list_box_win` with `list_box`, it will give the same error, but with the dict of items that I have in my taskbar

Comment: btw the icon that I am accessing is located in the hidden icons

Comment: This is the app context menu, so you have to connect to the application and access it from the app object: usually something like `app.ContextMenu` for `backend="uia"`. Only tray icons are part of `explorer.exe`.